# Data Stored in Session Will not Detect Context Attachment Correctly

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a list of a custom entity that I store in a session so a user can page through the data in an asp.net mvc website. The user is not editing this list, but approves it after they look through everything.

```cs
 List<scholarship> ss = x.scholarshipSet.Where(m => m.requriements != null).ToList();

 Session["ListOfScholarships"] = ss;
```

Once they have looked through the list and click that it is approved, I then mark the date it was approved.

```cs
CrmDataContext x = new CrmDataContext();
List<scholarship> ss = (List<scholarship>)Session["ListOfScholarships"];
DateTime n = DateTime.Now;

    foreach (scholarship s in ss) {
        s.Approved = n;
           if (!x.IsAttached(s)) {
                 x.Attach(s);
             }
               x.UpdateObject(s);
      }
     x.SaveChanges();
```

This part of the code

```cs
if (!x.IsAttached(s)) {
     x.Attach(s);
}
```

is not working correctly. It gets inside the if statement, which specifically checks if the entity is attached already, then throws the error

```
The 'scholarship' entity is already attached to a context.
```

This does NOT happen if I do not use the session. How would it one second think the entity is not attached, and then realize it is attached the next? Why would a session cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to store the entity in the session, it has to be serialized.  I'm wondering if somehow that is messing up the information that CRM uses to determine if an entity is in the context.  Rather than using a Context for the update, you can just use the underlying IOrgranizationalService.

```
foreach (scholarship s in ss) {
    // Create a new object just in case someone has edited some other field on the object since it was retrieved.
    // This keeps the updated field from being overridden
    service.Update(new scholarship(){ Id = s.Id, Approved = n});
}
```

Comment: This is certainly a better work around than I came up with; I didn't realize you could update like that. If I don't get a better answer than this, I'll mark it later.